# Swift generic completion handler

Tags: swift, generics, completionhandler

I'm trying to figure out how to create a generic completion handler. Below is an example illustrating an example "internal" generic completion handler and the same generic completion handler as I would want to be able to create it if I could do that in "external" form. The problem is that I don't know how to write the equivalent of the `internalCompletion<T: MyEnum>...` in a completion handler. I've written in the `externalCompletion` function what I'd imagine it could look like: something along the lines of `func externalCompletion(_ completer<T: MyEnum>: ((T) -> Void) where T: Hashable))`, but this is obviously not correct. Is what I'm trying to do possible? My hunch is that swift won't let the completion handler remain generic, always requiring a type casting at the function level, which would defeat the purpose per my example (i.e. `func externalCompletetion<T: MyEnum>(_ completer: ((T) -> Void)) where T: Hashable`, the problem with this being I would have to choose between EnumA, EnumB, and EnumC, not being able to run the completer on all three.)

```
typealias MyEnumKeyedData<T: MyEnum> = [T: String] where T: Hashable

// MARK : - MyEnum Protocol

protocol MyEnum {
  static func all<T: MyEnum>(_:T.Type) -> [T] where T: Hashable
  static var all: [MyEnum] { get }
}
extension MyEnum {
  static func all<T: MyEnum>(_:T.Type) -> [T] where T: Hashable { return Self.all as! [T] }
}

// MARK : - My enums

enum EnumA: MyEnum {
  case first
  static var all: [MyEnum] { return [EnumA.first]}
}
enum EnumB: MyEnum {
  case first
  static var all: [MyEnum] { return [EnumB.first]}
}
enum EnumC: MyEnum {
  case first
  static var all: [MyEnum] { return [EnumC.first]}
}

// MARK : - MyEnum Data Iterator

class MyDataEnumIterator {
  var dataA: MyEnumKeyedData<EnumA> = [:]
  var dataB: MyEnumKeyedData<EnumB> = [:]
  var dataC: MyEnumKeyedData<EnumC> = [:]

  func updateData<T: MyEnum>(_ key: T, _ value: String) where T: Hashable {
    switch T.self {
    case is EnumA.Type: dataA[key as! EnumA] = value
    case is EnumB.Type: dataB[key as! EnumB] = value
    case is EnumC.Type: dataC[key as! EnumC] = value
    default: fatalError("Enum does not exist")
    }
  }

  // Internal (This works)

  func internalEnumIterator() {
    for key in EnumA.all(EnumA.self) { internalCompletion(key) }
    for key in EnumB.all(EnumB.self) { internalCompletion(key) }
    for key in EnumC.all(EnumC.self) { internalCompletion(key) }
  }

  func internalCompletion<T: MyEnum>(_ key: T) where T: Hashable {
    let value = "\(key)"
    updateData(key, value)
  }

  // External (This obviously doesn't, just sketching the idea)

  func externalEnumIterator(_ completer<T: MyEnum>: ((T) -> Void) where T: Hashable)  {
    for key in EnumA.all(EnumA.self) { completer(key) }
    for key in EnumB.all(EnumB.self) { completer(key) }
    for key in EnumC.all(EnumC.self) { completer(key) }
  }
}

// MARK : - Test cases (internal works, external does not, just sketching example)

let iterator = MyDataEnumIterator()
iterator.externalEnumIterator({ <T: MyEnum> (T) where T: Hashable in
  let value = "\(key)"
  iterator.updateData(key, value)
})
iterator.internalEnumIterator()
```

Comment: Can you please make a minimum example to simplify things?

Comment: This is so incredibly needlessly complex. None of these generics are necessary.

Comment: I know. I was just playing with the generics. Your solution is obviously better in practice

Comment: To add to my statement: None of those generics are actually even used. I can't find a single spot where the compiler is instantiating more than a single version of any of those generic functions

Comment: You would need to, though, for something like `func set<T: MyEnum>(_ data: [T: String?]) where T: Hashable { data.forEach{self[$0] = $1} }`. That's where the generic playing started, then got interested in the closure question.

Comment: Yeah that might. Even then I'm not sure. Doesn't warrant any of the other craziness, however

Comment: Fair enough. I've adopted yours. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version of the code with the minimal changes necessary to get it going

```
typealias MyEnumKeyedData<T: MyEnum> = [T: String] where T: Hashable

// MARK : - MyEnum Protocol

protocol MyEnum {
    static func all<T: MyEnum>(_:T.Type) -> [T] where T: Hashable
    static var all: [MyEnum] { get }
}
extension MyEnum {
    static func all<T: MyEnum>(_:T.Type) -> [T] where T: Hashable { return Self.all as! [T] }
}

// MARK : - My enums

enum EnumA: MyEnum {
    case first
    static var all: [MyEnum] { return [EnumA.first]}
}
enum EnumB: MyEnum {
    case first
    static var all: [MyEnum] { return [EnumB.first]}
}
enum EnumC: MyEnum {
    case first
    static var all: [MyEnum] { return [EnumC.first]}
}

// MARK : - MyEnum Data Iterator

class MyDataEnumIterator {
    var dataA: MyEnumKeyedData<EnumA> = [:]
    var dataB: MyEnumKeyedData<EnumB> = [:]
    var dataC: MyEnumKeyedData<EnumC> = [:]

    func updateData(_ key: MyEnum, _ value: String) {
        switch key {
        case let key as EnumA: dataA[key] = value
        case let key as EnumB: dataB[key] = value
        case let key as EnumC: dataC[key] = value
        default: fatalError("Enum does not exist")
        }
    }

    // Internal (This works)

    func internalEnumIterator() {
        for key in EnumA.all(EnumA.self) { internalCompletion(key) }
        for key in EnumB.all(EnumB.self) { internalCompletion(key) }
        for key in EnumC.all(EnumC.self) { internalCompletion(key) }
    }

    func internalCompletion<T: MyEnum>(_ key: T) where T: Hashable {
        let value = "\(key)"
        updateData(key, value)
    }

    func EnumIterator(_ compeltitionHandler: (MyEnum) -> Void) {
        for key in EnumA.all(EnumA.self) { compeltitionHandler(key as MyEnum) }
        for key in EnumB.all(EnumB.self) { compeltitionHandler(key as MyEnum) }
        for key in EnumC.all(EnumC.self) { compeltitionHandler(key as MyEnum) }
    }
}


let iterator = MyDataEnumIterator()

iterator.EnumIterator{ key in
    let value = "\(key)"
    iterator.updateData(key, value)
}
iterator.internalEnumIterator()
```

Here is a sane version of the code that removes all the nonsense, and adds subscript syntax:

```
// MARK : - MyEnum Protocol

protocol MyEnum {
    static func all() -> [MyEnum]
}

// MARK : - My enums

enum EnumA: MyEnum {
    case first
    static func all() -> [MyEnum] { return [EnumA.first] }
}
enum EnumB: MyEnum {
    case first
    static func all() -> [MyEnum] { return [EnumB.first] }
}
enum EnumC: MyEnum {
    case first
    static func all() -> [MyEnum] { return [EnumC.first] }
}

// MARK : - MyEnum Data Iterator

class MyDataEnumIterator {
    var dataA = [EnumA: String]()
    var dataB = [EnumB: String]()
    var dataC = [EnumC: String]()


    subscript(key: MyEnum) -> String? {
        get {
            switch key {
            case let key as EnumA: return dataA[key]
            case let key as EnumB: return dataB[key]
            case let key as EnumC: return dataC[key]
            default: fatalError("Enum does not exist")
            }
        }
        set {
            switch key {
            case let key as EnumA: dataA[key] = newValue
            case let key as EnumB: dataB[key] = newValue
            case let key as EnumC: dataC[key] = newValue
            default: fatalError("Enum does not exist")
            }
        }
    }

    func EnumIterator(_ body: (MyEnum) -> Void) {
        EnumA.all().forEach(body);
        EnumB.all().forEach(body);
        EnumC.all().forEach(body);
    }
}


let iterator = MyDataEnumIterator()
iterator.EnumIterator{
    iterator[$0] = "\($0)"
}
```